Change character used for interaction term
Consider the following example:
library(gtsummary)

tbl_regression(lm(mpg~cyl*disp,mtcars))

Which results in:

Can I change the character for the interaction term to something like • instead of *? If so, how?
I don't like the asterisk, I like the dot more.

You can use modify_table_body() to change the label. Below I use the unicode for a 'middle dot'.
    tbl_regression(lm(mpg~cyl*disp,mtcars)) %>% 
      modify_table_body(~ .x %>% 
                          dplyr::mutate(label = ifelse(label == "cyl * disp", 
"cyl \U000B7 disp",  
label )))


